# merging lists in a list of lists that has one similar item in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of list with strings in it:

```
list = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["a", "e"],["f","d"],["x","y"]]
```

Now i want to merge all lists, that have 1 similar item in it like this:

```
grouped_list = [["a", "b", "e"],["c","d","f"],["x","y"]]
```

my code is this til now:

```
 list = [["a","b"],["b","c"],["d","e"],["x","y"]]
 clist = list.copy()
 result = []
 counter = 0
 del_list = []
 def oneofsame(L1, L2):
     counter = 0
     for i in L1:
         for j in L2:
             if i == j:
                 counter += 1
     if counter == 0:
         return False
     else:
         return True

 for l in list:
     try:
         del clist[clist.index(l)]
     except:
         pass
     result.append([])
     for i in l:
         for cl in clist:
             if oneofsame(l, cl):
                 for j in l:
                     if j not in result[counter]:
                         result[counter].append(j)
                 for j in cl:
                     if j not in result[counter]:
                         result[counter].append(j)
                 del_list.append(cl)
             else:
                 result.append(cl)
                 del_list.append(cl)
             for j in del_list:
                 del clist[clist.index(j)]
             del_list = []     
     counter += 1

 del_list = []
 cresult = result.copy()
 for i in range(len(cresult)-1, 0, -1):
     if cresult[i] == []:
         del result[i]
 print(result)
```

but this code doesn't merge all of my example input (I can't paste my example input, because its sensitiv data)

Comment: It's not clear what your grouping 'rule' is. Could you explain further?

Comment: Explain the criteria for grouping, give at least one more example input/output, and show that you have researched the question yourself

Comment: The grouping ruile appears to be merge any lists that have elements in common (a and d are the common elements that cause grouping in the example, a in 1st & 3rd lists, d in 2nd & 4th).. The grouping is a set of the merged lists.

Comment: I have an answer for this, I understant what the OP is asking.

Comment: @b-fg You can vote to re-open

Comment: Cannot find where to vote to do so.

Comment: @b-fg you can vote on the left side of the question

Comment: I mean vote to reopen, not just upvote the question.

Comment: I thought it's the same thing. I can't find a answer on metastack too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

For each pair:

- if we find a group that contains one of the values, we append the pair to the group
- if we find a second group that contains the other value, we merge the groups.
- if we found no matching group, then our pair constitutes a new one.

---

```
def group_equals(lst):
    groups = []

    for pair in lst:
        pair = set(pair)
        equals_found = 0
        for idx, group in enumerate(groups):
            if group.intersection(pair):
                equals_found += 1
                if equals_found == 1:
                    # We found a first group that contains one of our values,
                    # we can add our pair to the group
                    group.update(pair)
                    first_group = group
                elif equals_found == 2:
                    # We found a second group that contains the other one of 
                    # our values, we merge it with the first one
                    first_group.update(group)
                    del groups[idx]
                    break
        # If none of our values was found, we create a new group
        if not equals_found:
            groups.append(pair)

    return [list(sorted(group)) for group in groups]

tests = [ [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["b", "c"]],  # all equal
          [["a","b"],["c","d"],["a", "e"],["f","d"]],
          [["a","b"],["c","d"],["a", "e"],["f","d"],["x","y"]]
        ]

for lst in tests:
    print(group_equals(lst))

# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
# [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'f']]
# [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'f'], ['x', 'y']]
```

Comment: for a more complex dataset like this[1], you need to remove the "for lst in tests:" and run the function direct on the list named "tests" otherwise it will give you something like this[2].

[1]&[2] https://pastebin.com/uvFqF1hX

Comment: The last loop runs the function on 3 different cases, to verify that the output of each of these test cases is correct. That's why the different cases are grouped in a list named `tests`. Of course you need to call the function on your data directly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my below code will solve your problem:

```
import itertools
import copy

lista = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["a", "e"],["f","d"],["x","y"]] #[["a","b"],["e","d1"],["a", "e"],["a","d"],["d","y"]]

def grouped_list(lista):
    aa = []
    bbc = copy.deepcopy(lista)
    flag = False

    for a, b in itertools.combinations(lista,2):
        bb = a+b

        if len(set(bb)) < len(bb):
            flag = True
            cc = list(set(bb))
            cc.sort()

            if cc not in aa: aa.append(cc)
            if a in lista:   lista.remove(a) 
            if b in lista:   lista.remove(b)

    if lista:        aa = aa + lista
    if not flag:     return bbc
    else:            return grouped_list(aa)


print ("Grouped list -->", grouped_list(lista))
```

Feel free to ask/suggest anything in the above code.